# Why doesn't the HTML call the main method of the JS?

Tags: javascript, html

The problem I have is that when I call `onload()`, the `main()` function of the script.js file should be executed, but it is not. When I delete the `import ...` line, the `main()` function is ready to be called, but I can't because I want to call another function from the other JS file.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="main()">
    
    <div id="allScreen">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
import { createNewScreen } from "./createScreen";

let screens = [];

function main(){
    screens.push(createNewScreen());
    document.getElementById('allScreen').appendChild(screens[0]);
}
```

createScreen.js:

```
export function createNewScreen(){

    let screen = document.createElement('div');

    screen.style.width = '500px';
    screen.style.height = '300px';
    screen.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';

    return screen;
}
```

The `main()` function should be called.

Comment: Are you getting an error when loading `script.js`? I think you have to use `type="module"` if you want to use `import`.

Comment: I get the error message: Uncaught SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module. I wrote `<script type="module" ...>` and I get other message that said, it can not find the `main()`.

Comment: Flaw in your logic `.appendChild(screens[0]);` why are you appending the first index and not the one you just created? Push adds to the end of the array so you are always selecting the first and not the last element of that array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three problems there:

1. Your script won't be loaded at all, because you can't use `import` in a non-module script, and you're loading that file as a non-module script
2. If you did load it as a module script, `main` wouldn't be a global anymore because top-level declarations in modules aren't globals, and you can only call global functions from old `onXYZ`-attribute-style event handler (one of the many reasons not to use them).
3. Unless you have a bundling step you didn't mention, you need to include the file extension on your `import` for `createScreen.js`. The JavaScript engine doesn't do fancy resolution like some bunders (and Node.js) do where you can leave it off.

Instead:

1. Use `type="module"` on your script tag, and
2. Run your `main` function directly. Modules (unlike non-module scripts) aren't executed until the HTML is loaded, so you don't have to wait for the `load` event. (You *could*, though, if you really want to wait for all images to be loaded and such, by using `addEventListener` on `body` to hook up a `load` handler. You'd want to check [`document.visibilityState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState) to see whether it had already fired. But in general, best not to wait that long.)
3. Include the extension in the module specifier in the `import`:

   ```
   import { createNewScreen } from "./createScreen.js";
   // −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^
   ```

Here's an example of #1 and #2 (can't do a separate module with file name using Stack Snippets, unfortunately):

```html
<script type="module">
main();
function main(){
    const standIn = document.createElement("div");
    standIn.textContent = "Added by main";
    document.getElementById("allScreen").appendChild(standIn);
}
</script>
<div id="allScreen">
</div>
```

Notice how `main` is able to get the element, even though it's defined after the script. That's because of the way modules are auto-deferred.

Comment: I wrote my code directly in `<script>` and above the `main()`, also the `import ...` and I get the error message that said Loading of the module of "http://...../createScreen" was blocked due to an unapproved MIME type ("text/html") AND failed to load the module. I don't have the `"text"/html` just `type="module"`.

Comment: @codeWcay - Looks like an issue with your `import` declaration. I've added a #3 above. (Most likely, you're getting that MIME type because your server is responding to a request for `./createScreen` with a 404.)

Answer (score 2):

You can only use `import` inside a [module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules).

You have to load the `<script>` as a module with `type="module"`.

If you had looked at the browser's developer tools Console, you would have seen an error message when you tried to use `import`. **Always use the Console when debugging your code!**.

Top level variables in modules are scoped to the **module**, they are not globals. (This is a good thing. Globals are a good way to make hard-to-maintain, fragile code.).

Intrinsic event attributes (like `onload`) depend on globals. This is one of many reasons that they are best avoided. Now we don't have to worry about Internet Explorer 8 we can freely use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

You can use it to call `main` inside your JS file.

That said, there doesn't seem to be any reason to wait for the `load` event. Instead you can just call `main()` or move its contents to the top level of the module. Modules aren't run immediately so the DOM will be ready by the time it triggers.